# Nginx loads a site with 200 status and returns no data, and there are no errors anywhere

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I recently moved a wordpress site from one nginx setup on an EC2 instance, to a different EC2 instance, also with NGINX.

1. I am getting a 200 status when loading the website in the browser.
2. there are no bad lines in the mysql logs
3. the  nginx access logs are just the regular access logs. nothing abnormal
4. the nginx error logs look like this:

   - 2015/11/14 03:23:31 [notice] 7548#0: signal process started
   - 2015/11/14 03:35:10 [notice] 28774#0: signal process started
   - 2015/11/14 03:39:21 [notice] 28783#0: signal process started
   - 2015/11/14 03:39:53 [notice] 28788#0: signal process started
   - 2015/11/14 03:46:20 [notice] 28899#0: signal process started
5. the php logs are normal looking too:

   - [14-Nov-2015 03:44:08] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 28838
   - [14-Nov-2015 03:44:08] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
   - [14-Nov-2015 03:58:32] NOTICE: Terminating ...
   - [14-Nov-2015 03:58:32] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
   - [14-Nov-2015 03:58:32] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 28980
   - [14-Nov-2015 03:58:32] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
   - [14-Nov-2015 04:28:40] NOTICE: Terminating ...
   - [14-Nov-2015 04:28:40] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
   - [14-Nov-2015 04:28:40] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 29059
   - [14-Nov-2015 04:28:40] NOTICE: ready to handle connections

When I point the server block at a static directory with just a `index.html` containing `"hello world"` file, it runs.

When I change the name of the file to `index.php` it stops working.

that almost guarantees its a PHP problem. but I really don't know what I'd need to change.

Comment: Did you check also file/directory permissions?

Comment: Check your PHP logs. A blank page is a strong signal of a PHP fatal error.

Comment: @EdCottrell php logs look normal,too

Comment: @pejuko file directory permissions of the site being served? what would be an appropriate permissions level / chmod number for the files?

Comment: @Kristian What you posted looks like the php-fpm log, not the PHP error log. Look for the PHP error log. Most likely, it's in the home directory of your site and named `error_log`.

Comment: @Kristian I think directories should have 0755 and files 0744 if the server doesn't need write access. if the server needs write access then for directory it is 0777 and for files 0766